# How would you convert this method into a ternary expression?

Tags: java, oop

I want to convert those if-statements into a ternary operator expression, but I've been struggling since I haven't had the need to use them that much. The code essentially replaces the characters '1' with 'i', removes characters that are not letters, and also removes upper-case letters by enqueuing elements that don't meet those conditions.

```
private static Iterable<Character> transformationA(Queue<Character> q) {
    Queue<Character> retq = new Queue<>();
    for(Character c: q) {
        if(c.equals('1')) {
            retq.enqueue('i');
        }
        if(Character.isLowerCase(c)) {
            retq.enqueue(c);
        }
    }
    return retq;
}
```

Edit: thanks for your comments, code and suggestions.

Comment: You can't really do this with a ternary expression, because a ternary expression always evaluates to _something_, whereas in many cases, you don't want to enqueue _anything_.

Comment: Do you realise that ternary operators don't necessarily "improve" your code? I know some people who think they are a really bad language feature.

Comment: Why do you think you need a ternary operator expression here? What value will it add to your code? As Dawood ibn Kareem says, a ternary operator must evaluate to **something** for every case. However, your current code ignores some cases. So you cannot use a ternary operator.

Comment: The conditional operator (calling it "the operator with 3 operands" is just silly) is used in an  **expression**.   What you have is not a conditional expression but a conditional **statement**.  They are not interchangeable.

Comment: @user16632363 The phrase "the operator with 3 operands" is not silly, it is literally the definition of [ternary operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation). The word *ternary* comes from Latin "terni" for "three at once".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Ternary operation does not fit

[As commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69293049/how-would-you-convert-this-method-into-a-ternary-expression#comment122473378_69293049), a [ternary operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation) is not appropriate to your code. A ternary operation in Java is an expression, returning a result.

In your case, you do not have a "if x is true, return y, otherwise return z" situation. In your case you may enqueue an `I`, *or* you may enqueue a lowercase letter, *or* you may do nothing (thereby ignoring that nth character).

## Unicode code points

The `char` type (and its `Character` wrapper class) are legacy, essentially broken. As a 16-bit value, the `char` type is incapable of representing even half of the characters defined in Unicode.

Instead use Unicode [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) integer numbers.

- Pass in a collection of `int` or `Integer` (or `IntStream`) rather than `Character` objects. And actually, I would just pass in a [`CharSequence`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/CharSequence.html) (the interface for `String`, etc.).
- To see if the code point represents the character for the digit `1`, check for a code point number of `49` (decimal), the ASCII/Unicode number for the digit `1`: `if( codePoint == 49 ) { … }` where `codePoint` is an `int`/`Integer`.
- For lowercase check, pass the code point integer: `if( Character.isLowerCase( codePoint ) ) { … }`.

Comment: Is it only the use of the `Character` class that you disapprove of in the previous answer, or is there another reason you consider it an inappropriate solution?

Comment: @jaco0646 The other Answer’s code is a fine solution and works just as well with a stream of code pont `int` values (`IntStream`) such as that produced by [`String#codePoints`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#codePoints()). However, as an Answer it could use discussion, as a mere code snippet is not enough to qualify as a good Answer on Stack Overflow. And it should explain why it does not involve the ternary expression requested in the Question. And `Queue` as an interface cannot be instantiated.  But I already upvoted despite that lack.

Comment: The previous answer does involve a ternary expression.

Comment: @jaco0646 Yes, but not the ternary requested by the Question: *convert those if-statements into a ternary operator expression*

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
inQueue.stream()
    .map(c -> '1'.equals(c)?'i':c)
    .filter(Character::isLowerCase)
    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(Queue::new)));
```